# World-volume (higher) gauge theory on D-branes

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, branes

It is well known that if one constructs ordinary WZW type sigma model for string action, it is possible whenever they find a cocycle in appropriate Chevalley-Eilenberg algebra. If I understand it correctly, this approach gives the right actions in cases, when we do not consider so-called "background branes" (this terminology is taken from the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5264 ). When we do consider also background branes, our theory effectively obtains new (higher) gauge field on its world-volume.

*If I work with theory of open strings and impose D-branes as a background branes to this theory, what is the relevant gauge field on its world-sheet and why?*

According to my former understanding, it should be Chan-Paton gauge field, but Chan-Paton gauge field probably lives on the world-volume of D-branes and has more likely something to do with terms in DBI action. But I am pretty confused about it, I would be glad for proper explanation.

---

*Later edit:* More careful reading of mentioned article has shown that on this very background brane there appears the higher gauge field in question, not on the world-sheet of a string. It sounds plausible, because then commonly known (super) Yang-Mills theories on the world-volume of D-brane are probably just low-energy limits of such higher WZW theories with higher gauge fields on their world-volume.

Where my current understanding wanes is the description of suitable theory for strings with such background-brane environment. One has to consider some physics of string's boundaries, which are charged under these higher gauge fileds. But I am not aware of good arguments for that.

Comment: Are you asking about the 2-form B-field? It's always there I think (except in type I when it gets projected out?).

Comment: 2-form B-field comes to the theory as a higher gauge field living on spacetime, I think it is permanent ingredient of all WZW theories and do not reflect the existence of any background-brane. If do not agree, please explain me this in little more details.

Comment: In string theory it comes from the worldsheet modes $a_i a_j |0\rangle$ with anti-symmetric combinations of indices. Sometimes the GSO projection forbids these. String theory has no fundamental fields. Everything emerges from the string (supposedly).

Comment: For the later edit: Are you already in BV fields? Because that will complicate the reduction to a familar SYM or DBI action because you'll need $\mathcal{L}_{g.f.}$ and then probably a messy change of coordinates.

Comment: @AHusain: Why do we need to fix gauge degrees of freedom when passing from original action with higer gauge fields to SYM? I hope it would resemble the technique of obtaining SYM from DBI (expanding in small $\alpha$ parametr, neglecting some terms, etc.)

Comment: There are reducible symmetries ($B \to B + d\alpha, \alpha \to \alpha + df$ in the case of 2-form $B$) so when you quantize BRST won't cut it. Then you write the BV extension. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BV-BRST+formalism). Follow links therein for the procedure.

Comment: Is your claim that for reasons of quantization of higher gauge theories we need to have higher ghosts which do not have their counterparts in  SYM theories? And thus there can't be any straighforward way to state that SYM is an effective theory for this higher gauge theory? If I get you wrong, please correct me. And thank you for your remark.